# How do you auto import libraries in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Usually in IntelliJ you have a shortcut for auto importing libraries.

Is there an equivalent for Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 9):

In the current version, 1.11.2, you can put your cursor in the error line.

You will see a bulb in the line number. Then click it or press the shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (Quick Fix).

That will pop up a import hint window, as follows

[image]

Comment: Is it available for C#?

Comment: quick fix (in windows Ctrl + .) should also pop up the hint when you use it in the C# project.

Answer (score -1):

Currently there is no support for this in Visual Studio Code, but it's a good idea for an extension.